# How to extract variables into a text file from Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, bots, watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I want to be able to store context variables into a text file. 
Im using this code:

```
"context" : {
    "number_extract" : "<? input.text.extract('[\\d]+',0) ?>"
}
```

to extract variables into and store in context variable. But now i want to be able to extract it from Watson Assistant for e.g. store it into a text file or any other format. Is this possible or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store the context from variables in [text files or in a database](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). [Watson Assistant allows to make programmatic calls from within a dialog](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions). The code that is invoked would then take care of writing the extracted information to the file or database.

I wrote a [tutorial that uses the extracted information to store it in a database or to search in that database with extracted search terms](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). The code is on GitHub, so you can see how it is done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know if there are any other methods of extracting variables and storing them into a text file or any other format?